# How to add extra properties to migration in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages without deleting the previous migration or database in EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I'm making a project ASP.NET Core Razor Pages. I'm using Entity Framework Core in my project for a registration module; I wanted to add extra fields of my own as well with the features provided by the EF Core. So I created a User class with an additional field. I added the migration from package manager console and updated the database.

The problem is when I am adding 1 more property and trying to migrate, it gives me an error, so I deleted the migration from the migration folder, deleted the database, and generated the migration with new properties.

I feel this is certainly not a good way of doing it.

ApplicationUser.cs file:

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The reason your question is downvoted is because it is poorly researched or unclear. Specifically, you don't show the error that you are getting - are we supposed to guess it? More important, your problem is specific to Microsoft Identity; and you never mention it. Seems like you don't even realize it. `ApplicationUser` class doesn't add anything to understanding your problem. For all these reasons downvotes are quite deserved

Comment: What is the error message it gives you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating with Code First Approach takes little extra care w.r.t Database First Approach.

Initially, you must enable migrations for the project

`Enable-Migrations  -ContextTypeName  DBNAME.StoreContext`

This will create a migration folder with the Configuration.cs file.
Next, we need to make our migration run. This is where you need to add an extra step to an existing database. If we create a migration now, it will attempt to add all our entities to the database. This will not work because other tables already exist in the database, so we need to create an initial blank migration and then later we will be able to add a migration for any new changes. To create blank migration execute this command

`Add-Migration  InitialCreate  -IgnoreChanges`

The key part of this command is the -IgnoreChanges flag, which ensures that migration is created that effectively does nothing. Running it will add an entry to the migrations table in the database, thus creating a snapshot of its original schema.

Next, run the update-database command to update the existing database with the initial migration. A new migrations table will now have been created in the *DBNAME* database.

Following this, you can add your properties, and after that execute this statement
`Add-Migration add_classname_propertyname`

After that run, the `update-database` command and you are good to go.

Comment: thank you so much sir....atleast got some proper idea.so sir now if i add a property in that above mentioned class then i have to do (Add-Migration  InitialCreate  -IgnoreChanges)or i have to run the command first(make a blank migration) and then add something in the class?

Comment: Even if you have added something, i suspect it will be an issue